# What's the font-end IE version compatibility debug tools (easy shifting from IE 8 9 10 11) on Win8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, version

Compatibility issues are always front-end headache. need Emulators to test with diff browser versions.

As we known by default it's not allowed to install older IE versions on latest Win8 directly. 
instead of using virtual machines or sandbox, 
or online tools such as morden.IE / browser stack (need network or payment)

Are there any tools for front-end debugging of different IE versions that can be installed on Win8 for such kind of font-end cross-ie-version debugging?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hit F12 inside of IE.  There are developer tools built in to IE 9/10/11.

The last tab on dev tools will give you options for emulating different versions of IE (note that the emulation isn't perfect, however)

Comment: thanks for the fastest comment, yup not perfect, but at least can emulate, not as inefficient as using virtual environment or using multiple OS. :)

Comment: Sure thing.  Feel free to accept the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: first give you an upvote! and will see if there are other answers. :)